# Ordenar resultado com 4 colunas diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sintaxe

Tenho uma tabela com 4 colunas diferentes, 2 delas indicando o inicio (data e hora) e outras 2 indicando fim (também data e hora). Existe um meio de ordenar o resultado de forma que ele de prioridade ao evento mais recente? por exemplo: Se o fim for mais recente (data + hora) ele ordenaria pelo fim e se o inicio fosse mais recente (data + hora) ele ordenaria pelo mesmo. Obrigado

Pratico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo de sentença que gostaria que seguisse esse comportamento na sua pergunta?

Comment: Qual banco? MySql, SqlServer, Oracle?

Comment: MSSQL @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: A perdão não vi a tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como estão esses dados, mas vou supor que é tudo `VARCHAR` pra esta resposta. Dependendo dos comentários eu mudo.

Penso que a melhor abordagem seria com um `SELECT` dentro de outro, criando mais duas colunas `DATETIME` para que haja uma estrutura de dados capaz de realizar a ordem corretamente.

```
SELECT NOME, DTINI, HRINI, DTFIM, HRFIM
FROM (
    SELECT NOME, DTINI, HRINI, DTFIM, HRFIM, CONVERT(DATETIME, DTINI + ' ' + HRINI) AS DATACOMPLETA_INICIAL, CONVERT(DATETIME, DTFIM + ' ' + HRFIM) AS DATACOMPLETA_FINAL
    FROM SUATABELA
    WHERE ... -- Coloque aqui sua condição Where
) 
ORDER BY DATACOMPLETA_INICIAL DESC, DATACOMPLETA_FINAL DESC
```

Comment: São varchars, não consegui testar ainda pois estou sem acesso a VPN da empresa, amanha posto meus avanços. Obrigado